# unable to execute 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I am a newbie to linux and was trying to install Ansible in virtual environment using pip.

when I run the command it failing with the following error. Can you please help me in fixing this issue.

whenever I try to install any package I am getting unmet dependencies python-minimal

```
 (ansible1.9.4) vkolluru@vkolluru-Precision-5510:~/ansible/ansible1.9.4$ pip install ansible==1.9.4
Collecting ansible==1.9.4
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible==1.9.4) (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible==1.9.4) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible==1.9.4) (3.12)
Collecting pycrypto>=2.6 (from ansible==1.9.4)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ansible==1.9.4) (2.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jinja2->ansible==1.9.4) (1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.5 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version < "3" in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (1.0.19)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography>=1.5->paramiko->ansible==1.9.4) (2.18)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycrypto ... error
  Complete output from command /home/vkolluru/ansible/ansible1.9.4/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-7UDSud/pycrypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-Fti5ge --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
  copying lib/Crypto/pct_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
  copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
  copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
  copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash

  copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
  copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
  copying lib/Crypto/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
  copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_PSS.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
  running build_ext
  running build_configure
  checking for gcc... gcc
  checking whether the C compiler works... yes
  checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
  checking for suffix of executables...
  checking whether we are cross compiling... no
  checking for suffix of object files... o
  checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
  checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
  checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
  checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... no
  checking for __gmpz_init in -lmpir... no
  checking whether mpz_powm is declared... no
  checking whether mpz_powm_sec is declared... no
  checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
  checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
  checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
  checking for ANSI C header files... yes
  checking for sys/types.h... yes
  checking for sys/stat.h... yes
  checking for stdlib.h... yes
  checking for string.h... yes
  checking for memory.h... yes
  checking for strings.h... yes
  checking for inttypes.h... yes
  checking for stdint.h... yes
  checking for unistd.h... yes
  checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
  checking limits.h usability... yes
  checking limits.h presence... yes
  checking for limits.h... yes
  checking stddef.h usability... yes
  checking stddef.h presence... yes
  checking for stddef.h... yes
  checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
  checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
  checking for string.h... (cached) yes
  checking wchar.h usability... yes
  checking wchar.h presence... yes
  checking for wchar.h... yes
  checking for inline... inline
  checking for int16_t... yes
  checking for int32_t... yes
  checking for int64_t... yes
  checking for int8_t... yes
  checking for size_t... yes
  checking for uint16_t... yes
  checking for uint32_t... yes
  checking for uint64_t... yes
  checking for uint8_t... yes
  checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
  checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
  checking for memmove... yes
  checking for memset... yes
  configure: creating ./config.status
  config.status: creating src/config.h
  warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
  building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
  unable to execute 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, ansible
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command /home/vkolluru/ansible/ansible1.9.4/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-7UDSud/pycrypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-KXvJMH/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/vkolluru/ansible/ansible1.9.4/include/site/python2.7/pycrypto:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
    copying lib/Crypto/pct_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
    copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA512.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA384.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/HMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/hashalgo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/CAST.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/DES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/XOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ARC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ARC2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/py3compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/RFC1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/py21compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/randpool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/_number_new.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/SHAd256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/nt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/rng_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/fallback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/st_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_AES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_XOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_CAST.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_Blowfish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA384.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA512.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_HMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_chaffing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_rfc1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_KDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_importKey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_rpoolcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_SHAd256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_nt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_fallback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_generic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/Chaffing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/KDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_slowmath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_PSS.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
    running build_ext
    running build_configure
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
    unable to execute 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/vkolluru/ansible/ansible1.9.4/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-7UDSud/pycrypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-KXvJMH/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/vkolluru/ansible/ansible1.9.4/include/site/python2.7/pycrypto" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-7UDSud/pycrypto/
```

I see the gcc is avalable

```
(ansible1.9.4) vkolluru@vkolluru-Precision-5510:~/ansible/ansible1.9.4$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file not found error is likely confusing you and understandibly. I believe it is not that it can't find this compiler (else it wouldn't have an exit status) but that it can't find a source file to compile, object to link or header file to include.

Have you installed python-dev?

The dev packages (devel in the rpm world) have the header files that aren't needed to run a program but are needed to compile against it.